# Example such that $HN/N ~\mbox{char}~ G/N$ and $N~\mbox{char}~G$, but $H$ not characteristic in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $H/N$ is characteristic in $G/N$ and $N$ is characteristic in $G$, then $H$ is characteristic in $G$, a proof could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27491/question-about-characteristic-subgroups) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210695/question-on-proof-that-o-pc-c-cap-fg-1-for-c-c-gfg).
The notation, i.e. speaking about subgroups $H/N$ implies $N \le H$, for general subgroups we must write $HN/N$ to get a subgroup in $G/N$.

So now my question. Do you know an example of a subgroup $N \nleq H$ such that
$HN/N$ is characteristic in $G/N$, $N$ is characteristic in $G$, but $H$ is **not** characteristic in $G$?

Comment: Yes I know an example! It's easy to find examples in which $H$ is not normal in $G$, but perhaps you would prefer $H$ to be normal. We can still do it! Let $G=D_8$ be dihedral of order $8$. I'll leave you to choose $H$ and $N$.

Comment: Let $D_8 = \langle x, h \rangle$ with $x^2 = 1, h^4 = 1$. Then $N := \langle h \rangle$ is characteristic in $D_8$ and $D_8 / N \cong \mathbb Z/ 2\mathbb Z$. Also $H = \{ e, x, h^2, h^2x \}$ is normal, but not characteristic, further $HN/N = G/N$, and therefore it is characteristic as it is the whole group.

Comment: Yes that's right!